# Should I delete my answer if it's irrelevant to (one of) the question tags?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, wrong-answers

Years ago someone asked [How can I enforce uniqueness based on a condition in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866061/conditional-unique-constraint) to which I suggested a [Filtered Index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149263/621962).

Unfortunately, my answer is irrelevant to the OP because it doesn't apply to [sql-server-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005) (my mistake). That said, the answer is pretty popular and it continues to earn upvotes -well, until it draws meta's scouring gaze.

So, do I have a responsibility to remove that answer? How can the community best be served here?

Comment: IMO, leave the answer and specify explicitly that it is for `SQL Server 2008`. Looks like people have found that useful - "Thanks! I was searching the web and are using 2008 :)" (Comment with 9 upvotes)

Comment: Might want to direct them to a solution that works for 2005 by editing the question (e.g. "# If using SQL Server 2005 \n See \[so-and-so's answer\](link)").

Comment: I'd certainly add a "if you can upgrade to SQL 2008 (or above) you can use this" type comment.

Comment: Especially today, few programmers will google this question and expect an answer that's only appropriate for old SQL server versions.  Clearly your answer was future-proof :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, Leave your answer and explicitly state that it is for SQL Server 2008. In your answer you can also mention [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866100/961113) for SQL Server 2005.

I have seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c), where the OP asked for optional parameter in C#, The question was asked in 2008, when C# 4.0 wasn't out, Later that question got an answer with respect to C# 4.0 and was accepted. *(Now it has 300 upvotes)*. So the community has found it to be useful.

Same is the case with your answer, Search on Google for "conditional unique constraint" results in the said question being the first result. Users are finding it useful and hence the upvotes.